# String variables?

Tags: java, string

So I need to write a program that defines the String variable containing the name 'JOE BLOGGS'. I then need to printout in the console the 1st and 5th characters, How could I make a java program for this so that the name can also be changed and the program will still function correctly?

And then I have to extend the code to add (concatenate) the string ‘is an employee’ to JOE BLOGGS's name and convert the sentence to upper case, and print the resulting string to the screen, i.e.

JOE BLOGGS IS AN EMPLOYEE

Many thanks for your time:) I literally got no idea how to start as i'm quite new to Java.

Comment: You should really look up some introductory Java tutorials and come back with a more specific question when you've tried *something*...a good starting point might be [Oracle's tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).

Comment: Sigh, here's how to start: write some code, compile, fix compile errors, continue until compilation passes.  Have a congratulatory beer. Run your code, fix runtime errors, continue until it does what you want.  Have another congratulatory beer and stop until it wears off...believe me, your code will only get worse.  In short, try _something_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestClass().printChars("JOE BLOGGS", "is an employee");
}

public void printChars(String baseString, String additionalString) {
    System.out.println(baseString.charAt(1));
    System.out.println(baseString.charAt(5));
    System.out.println(baseString + " " + additionalString.toUpperCase());
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I feel like programming is just a bunch of Googling to answer my questions.

But never fear; here are a couple of hand-picked (although thoroughly unoriginal) links that I believe will answer all of your listed questions:

- [Oracle's Java Strings Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)
- [Oracle's java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

The Oracle tutorials I find surprisingly good.  On the second link, just search for *upper*, or better yet, skim the methods section.

Answer (score 0):

People should really stop posting their homeworks, and start trying at least...
If you're taking a java class, i'd say the least you have learned for you to do this homework is already enough.
Anyways:

```
public class classname{
public static void main(String[] args){

String str = "Your String goes here"; //so usually you should put JOE BLOGGS between the quotes
System.out.println(str.charAt(1));
System.out.println(str.charAt(5));
str += " is an employee";
str = str.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

Comment: It's not a homework, Its completely optional if I want to do it or not although the way I seem to learn is to be able to see how its done first so then iknow for future.. But thanks anyways